# Generate Typescript Types out of Google schema definition

Tags: typescript, schema.org, ajv, google-schemas

So in order to generate a proper feed based on Google's schema definition for e.g. `TVSeries` it is possible to fetch this definition from this url: [TVSeries Definition](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/tools/schema_livetv.json#/definitions/livetv/TVSeries)

and run tools like [AJV](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html) in order to validate your generated feed. This is all good and fine. However what would be even more developer friendly is to have already a static typing for the required validation schema. Currently I'm using this library in order to get static types for my schema definition: [Schema-DTS](https://github.com/google/schema-dts) and what is even more annoying is that those types are sometimes conflicting with the schema definition that google allows. For example very simple comparison:

- `TVSeries` from Schema.org does only allow for the `@context` to have `https://schema.org`, see: https://schema.org/TVSeries
- While the google schema definition allows

```json
              "enum": [
                "http://schema.org/",
                "http://schema.org",
                "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
                "http://schema.googleapis.com"
              ]
```

I've seen there is a library that allows for the generation of typescript types based on a specific schema called [schema-dts-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-dts-gen?activeTab=readme) but this library expects the path of an `.nt` NTriple file as argument. Maybe you guys have some good input how to generate  typescript typings based out of this [Google schema definition](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/tools/schema_livetv.json#/definitions/livetv/TVSeries)